# Where to find a Chainlink oracle?

Tags: chainlink

I'm trying to find a Chainlink oracle / node operator (specifically their job id and oracle address) so I can connect my blockchain smart contract to the internet and retrieve sports betting data.

market.link website disappeared a while ago, and I can't find another oracle marketplace.

Where can I find a Chainlink oracle these days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chainlink community oracle here.

Feel free to reference our [documentation](https://docs.linkwellnodes.io/services/direct-request-jobs/Jobs-and-Pricing) for our oracle addresses, job ids, and code samples of how to connect your smart contract to our Chainlink oracles on all major mainnet and testnet blockchains.

In general, your constructor will look something like this, but it will vary by chain:

```
constructor() ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender) {
    setChainlinkToken(0xb1D4538B4571d411F07960EF2838Ce337FE1E80E);  // Chainlink token contract on Arbitrum testnet    
    setOracleAddress(0xd36c6B1777c7f3Db1B3201bDD87081A9045B7b46);   // LinkWell's Arbitrum testnet oracle
    setJobId("a8356f48569c434eaa4ac5fcb4db5cc0");                   // LinkWell's uint256 job id
    setFeeInHundredthsOfLink(0);                                    // 0 LINK (free)
}
```

In general, if you're seeking a Chainlink oracle, you can do so by posting your question in the #operator-requests channel of the Chainlink Official Discord server.

Let me know if that helps, and if you have any other questions!

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful! Using your oracle, can I connect to any API that I like?

Comment: That's correct. Using our documentation, you can retrieve data from anywhere on the internet that supports an HTTP request (as well as configure any request method, body, and headers). If you need help storing any private information (ie, an API key) off-chain, feel free to reach out to us, as we can help you store that offline in our private datacenter. Glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch data from a specific API, maybe you can consider using the a service from Chainlink called [Chainlink Functions](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions). The advantage of  Chainlink functions is allow you to fetch the data from the API in a decentralized manner.

Some Chainlink functions use cases can be found [here](https://www.usechainlinkfunctions.com/).